# OpenGl, drawing multiple triangle objects C#

Tags: c#, opengl, render

So I have a Triangle class and I want to draw instance of my triangles but for some reasons, only one gets drawn and the logic behind it is beyond me.

I have been looking around but all I found is examples where all triangles are drawn on the same file.

This is the Triangle class:

```
 public class Triangle:IGameObject
 {
    Vector3 position;
    int speed;

    public Triangle(int speed, Vector3 vec) {
        this.speed = speed;
        position = new Vector3(vec);
    }
    public void Update() { }

    public void Render()
    {
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glRotated(speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3d(position.x, 0, 0);
            Gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            Gl.glVertex3d(position.y, 0, 0);
            Gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            Gl.glVertex3d(0, position.z, 0);

        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Here is the Form.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Triangle _trA = new Triangle(100, new Vector3(0.1f,-0.2f,0.2f));
    Triangle _trB = new Triangle(50, new Vector3(0.5f, 0.3f, -0.1f));
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _openGLControl.InitializeContexts();

        if (_fullscreen)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else {
            ClientSize = new Size(1280,720);
        }
    }

    void GameLoop()
    {
        Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        _trA.Render();
        _trB.Render();
        _openGLControl.Refresh();
    }
}
```

I think I have seen that I should clear the matrix after (or before) using it for the object but cannot figure that out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different issues:

**glPush/glPop**

You should call

```
Gl.glPushMatrix();
```

at the beginning of your `Render()` method, and

```
Gl.glPopMatrix();
```

at the end.

Otherwise the `glRotated()` get accumulated across all your calls. Calling `glPushMatrix()` duplicate your current ModelView matrix, then you can apply the rotation, and `glPopMatrix()` restore the previous one.

**glLoadIdentity**

You have to reset the ModelView matrix at the beginning of the GameLoop, by calling:

```
Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
Gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

This prevent any modification to accumulate from the previous frames.

**Accumulates Time.deltaTime**

I would guess that `Time.deltaTime` is the time, in seconds, that has past since your last frame. This is likely a constant, and then `speed*Time.deltaTime` is a constant too, so you always display the triangle rotated with the same angle, hence there is no movement. You should create a `angle` member, and increase it by calling `angle += speed * Time.deltaTime` at each GameLoop call.

**glRotated**

The three last arguments of `glRotated` indicate the axis of rotation around the one you are turning. Since you are using a 2D scene, I assume you want this axis to be the one the camera is looking at. Then you should use the axis `(0,0,1)` instead of `(angle,angle,angle)`.

**Conclusion**

Taking into account all these elements, your code should be:

```
public class Triangle:IGameObject
{
    Vector3 position;
    int speed;
    double angle;

    public Triangle(int speed, Vector3 vec) {
        this.speed = speed;
        position = new Vector3(vec);
        angle = 0;
    }
    public void Update()
    { 
        angle += speed*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        Gl.glPushMatrix();
        Gl.glRotated(angle,0,0,1);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

            Gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Gl.glVertex3d(position.x, 0, 0);
            Gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            Gl.glVertex3d(position.y, 0, 0);
            Gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            Gl.glVertex3d(0, position.z, 0);

        Gl.glEnd();
        Gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}

void GameLoop()
{
    // Update the scene
    _trA.Update();
    _trB.Update();

    // Draw the scene
    Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    _trA.Render();
    _trB.Render();
    _openGLControl.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to do it. All I get is a triangle on the top and two others that seems to be blinking. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @fafase Did you check that you rotate them with different values? print the values of the parameters in `Gl.glRotated(speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime,speed*Time.deltaTime);`, if they are equals of course you draw twice the same triangle (at the same position, so it appears as one)

Comment: Alright I get progression. What I have now is that I get the different triangle objects, but the issue remains on the rotation. They both rotate accumulating their rotation like you said. But if I put glPushMatrix() before the rotation, I simply get no movement.

Comment: @fafase With the instructions I provided, the code is correct and the error lies elsewhere. Can you edit your question to put the full code of the class where you define the "speed", as well as the full methods where you modify the speed, and call the Render() methods?

Comment: @fafase (and fast check just in case: make sure you *also* put the glPopMatrix(), otherwise of course it won't work)

Comment: And tadaaa. Thanks a whole bunch for that. I only can upvote once so you will have to get away with it. :) And thanks for taking the time to explain carefully. I realize I could not find any tutorial that would do it this way. Always, they show all object on the same methods. Now it is here!!!